# Tried to access UI constants from a non-visual Context

Tags: android, android-context

I am running my image viewer app in StrictMode to try to catch up memory leaks. In the activity that shows many thumbnails I see an error several times (probably once for each thumbnail):

```
E/ViewConfiguration: Tried to access UI constants from a non-visual Context:android.app.Application@7f56ef7UI constants, such as display metrics or window metrics, must be accessed from Activity or other visual Context. Use an Activity or a Context created with Context#createWindowContext(int, Bundle), which are adjusted to the configuration and visual bounds of an area on screen
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tried to access UI constants from a non-visual Context:android.app.Application@7f56ef7
```

This error is being triggered in the `getView` method of an `ImageAdapter` class extending `BaseAdapter`:

```
    ....
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thumbitem, parent, false);
            ...
```

This line `convertView = inflater.inflate...` is the one that gives the error.

The class has the following method that also triggers a `Tried to access visual service LayoutInflater from a non-visual Context` error:

```
ImageAdapter() {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    }
```

So it seems my `inflater` has a wrong context? Which would be the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which would be the correct one?

Your `Activity` is the correct `Context`. Ideally, call `getLayoutInflater()` on your `Activity` and use it.

Comment: Excellent! I just changed `ImageAdapter()` by `ImageAdapter(Context context)` and created the instance with `new ImageAdapter(this)` instead of `new ImageAdapter()`. The errors are gone. Thanks!

Comment: What should we do for the View classes including those defined in an XML file? For those inflated View classes, provides context from the constructors. But even with that context, it is throwing the same type of error.

Comment: @jettimadhuChowdary: `getContext()` called on a `View` should be giving you a suitable `Context`. If not, you might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing how you are inflating the layout and with details of the specific error that you see.